# String comparison in PHP doesn't make sense …

Tags: php

I have this really basic PHP code I can't figure out. In the example below, why do I get 'MATCH' when $i = 0, and not for the remaining rows …? It seems to be possible to workaround by using === instead of ==, but I can't understand why.

```
<?php

$text = 'foo bar';

for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo '<p>' . $i . ': ';

    if ($i == $text) {
        echo 'MATCH!';
    } else {
        echo 'NOPE';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to compare a string to a number?

Answer (score 1):

[PHP 8](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#saner-string-to-number-comparisons) has fixed that part.

Use [strcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) with `===`

```
// Use strcmp() function 
if (strcmp($i, $text) === 0) { // check datatype as well
    echo 'MATCH!';
} else {
    echo 'NOPE';
}
```

Comment: Aaah! Perfect! Thanks a lot. :-)